# "bad variable name : read:" in my script

Tags: bash

here is my script -

```
#!/bin/bash

echo "Enter date (YYYY-MM-DD) : "
read userdate

is_valid = date "+%Y-%m-%d" -d $userdate > /dev/null  2>&1

echo $is_valid
```

while I am trying to execute the script, its asking for "Enter date (YYYY-MM-DD) :", while I am entering date, its giving `: bad variable name 4: read: userdate` and `7: Syntax error: Bad fd number`

here is my system configuration detail -

```
Operating System: Ubuntu 20.04.5 LTS
        Kernel: Linux 5.4.0-99-generic
      Architecture: x86-64
```

Please help me to solve this, here I am just asking to get date from user input and checking that date is valid or not.

Thanks

Comment: To solve the line encoding easily, create a new blank file on Linux, and copy and paste the code from your question. It will then have correct line breaks.

Comment: The syntax of Line 6 is also invalid - if you want to assign the exit status, you will need to use something like `date "+%Y-%m-%d" -d "$userdate" > /dev/null  2>&1; is_valid=$?`